# Add centroid to plot - Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, centroid

In the following script I get the coordinates of and coins in an image, later they are plotted. How can I also add to the plot the centroid  calculated using stat (in red, marked as X)?

Script:

```
clc;
clear;
I = imread('coins.png');
imshow(I)
BW = im2bw(I);


BW_filled = imfill(BW,'holes');
stat = regionprops(BW_filled,'centroid');
boundaries = bwboundaries(BW_filled);

for k=1:10
    b = boundaries{k};
    plot(b(:,2),b(:,1),'g','LineWidth',3);
    hold on;
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add

```
plot(stat(k).Centroid(1), stat(k).Centroid(2), 'rx');
```

after

```
plot(b(:,2), b(:,1), 'g', 'LineWidth', 3);
hold on;
```

You can also apply any additional customisations to the centroid point like

```
plot(stat(k).Centroid(1), stat(k).Centroid(2), 'rx', 'LineWidth', 3);
```

#### Explanation

`stat(k)` will get the `k`th element of `stat`. `stat(k).Centroid` will extract the centroid as `[x, y]` and we can then reference the `x` coordinate of the centroid as `stat(k).Centroid(1)` and the `y` as `stat(k).Centroid(2)`.

---

#### Alternative Improvements

Some improvements to your code that I would suggest are

- Put `close all` at the top of the script. This will close all currently open figures
- Add `figure; hold on;` before the `for` loop and remove `hold on` from within the `for` loop. Calling `hold on;` multiple times is redundant.